# Bootstrap - Button in the same line of input of form-control

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to make the button stay on the same line as the input text that are in the previous forms-control.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-5 ">
    <label for="">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control " type="text" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-5 ">
    <label for="">E-mail</label>
    <input class="form-control " type="text" ">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this fiddle to see how it is:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/163069/)

I tried to put a "label" above the button tag. But I don't think that this is the better and the right way to do this.

Comment: just a hint: You need to assign a for attribute for the label (and an ID for the input) in order for it to work in an accessible way. Or wrap the input with the label. Otherwise you can just leave the label part out and use plain text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `align-items-end` on the flexbox row for the button to align at the bottom along with the inputs...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="form-group col-5 col-md-5 ">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control " type="text" id="inputHrDiariamaxima">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-5 col-md-5 ">
      <label for="">E-mail:</label>
      <input class="form-control " type="text" id="inputKmDiariamaxima">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-6 col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, note `-xs` no longer exists in Bootstrap 4.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xLc28pg5/

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if this works with bootstrap 3 too?

Comment: No, it does not

Answer (score 0):

Make your last column a flexbox and align items to end. Using bootstrap add `d-flex align-items-end` classes to your button containing column.